# Split Column by common text

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Using Power Bi and the following M code I have pulled desired data from the web.:

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/search.aspx?fcc=4"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "[id=""ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlSearchResults""] DIV"}, {"Column2", "[id=""ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlSearchResults""] A"}}, [RowSelector="[id=""ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlSearchResults""] DIV"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Although all the data has been pulled, its organised incorrectly within the table with column1 containing all of the desired data and column2 containing a duplicate of the chemical name as shown below.

[image]

I wish to be able to transform the data such that the chemical name and the comment in brackets e.g. (No Safety concern at current levels of intake when used as a flavouring agent) or (NOT COMPLETED) etc are in their own independent columns.

Because there is no consistent delimiter I am unsure how to achieve this. I am hoping that because there is common text between the two columns I can somehow deduct one from the other however as of yet I have only been able to do this with numerical data.

Comment: Do you want the Query to extract the information, or do you want to use Excel-Formulas to get this information?

Comment: Either really. If the query can extract the info in the desired format then great however I wasnt able to achieve this. I think transforming the query might be the best way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add a custom column with

```
=  Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],[Column2])
```

that should pull anything in column1 after the text in column 2